# Native JS in custom class: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, object, setinterval, innerhtml

Forgive the title, I'm not really sure what the problem is... I'm kind of guessing at this point.

This is my first attempt at a reusable class in Javascript. Here's a stripped down version of it:

```
Countdown = function ( elementID ) {
  this.timer = null;
  this.output = '';
  this.element = document.getElementById(elementID) || document.getElementById('countdown');
}

Countdown.prototype.start = function () {
  this.timer = setInterval(this.run, 1000);
}

Countdown.prototype.run = function () {
  this.output = 'test';
  this.element.innerHTML = this.output; /* THE PROBLEM IS HERE */
}

Countdown.prototype.toCalculatedTime = function () {
  this.start();
}

var c = new Countdown();
c.toCalculatedTime();

console.log(c);
```

I'm getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined"

at the line specified.

First, yes there is an element with an ID of 'countdown'. I've tried changing the name of the element, both in the markup and in the class. I've tried passing an element name upon instantiation of this class, and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

I really don't know what to make of this. In the console, it looks like my class is being constructed just fine.

Comment: The error message is telling you that your code is trying to do `something.innerHTML = whatver` in a case where `something` is `undefined`. Thus, `this.element` is `undefined` in that code.

Comment: But it shouldn't be. In the console, it looks like everything is being constructed just fine.

Comment: Passing `this.run` to `setTimeout` results in `this` being `window` when the function runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is saying that `this.element` is undefined. The reason why it is undefined is because `setTimeout` causes `run` to execute in window scope. You need to keep the scope bound to this by either using [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or a closure.

```
this.timer = setInterval(this.run.bind(this), 1000);
```

or

```
var that = this;
this.timer = setInterval(function(){ that.run(); }, 1000);
```

Comment: Interesting. I always seem to forget about the window object... *blushes* This worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Just so nobody else has to expose themselves as a hack (lol): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval#The_.22this.22_problem